# List of countries in the world where a tourist wouldn't come across stray dogs because they have a policy of removing strays off the streets

Tags: safety, countries

So far I have in my list (let's narrow down to urban and touristy areas):
USA
Canada
Australia (maybe NZ also)
Western Europe (not Central Europe)
Japan
South Korea

I guess I've already listed most of the countries that fit my requirement (correct me if any of the above countries need to be removed). Just checking to see if there are any more in Asia, Latin America and Africa?

Purpose of this question: I come from a country with packs of strays everywhere, and would like to travel to places which are *different* and *better* for relief/escape.

Comment: I think this is too broad to answer (certainly as a list of countries). Also, I wouldn't really say there are no stray dogs in the US or UK or Europe (although arguably they wouldn't be where a tourist would easily stumble across them).

Comment: Groenland would be one :)

Comment: That's a weird question, and I would doubt you could completely eliminate any country whatsoever.  There are just more or less chances of it happening, but (except maybe some micro-countries) there are probably in every single country.

Comment: The only valid answer to this is countries where there are no dogs - otherwise there is always a chance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not directly related to travel.

Comment: I'm guessing the people not understanding this question have never been to a country where stray dogs are commonplace (i.e. you'll encounter multiple on any typical walk in a typical town) and aggressive (guidebooks offer tips for stray dog standoffs). I can understand why anyone with a dog phobia would want to avoid such places. Bucharest is notorious for this, and I had several aggressive dog standoffs in Tonga (guidebook suggests carrying a stick in some areas to fend them off). Stray dogs are common in West Africa but (certainly in Sierra Leone) they're harmless - completely docile.

Comment: Since the vast majority of countries *don't* have a stray dog problem, maybe this question would be less broad if it was reversed? "In which countries are aggressive stray dogs a common problem for travelers?" seems like a good, answerable question

Comment: Um, there are totally stray dogs in Canada, Australia, NZ, and the US (source: have lived there, seen them)

Comment: @MarkMayo but stray dogs are not commonplace in, for example, New York City, where the last time I remember seeing a pack of strays was 1980 or '81.  In Sarajevo, on the other hand, one sees stray dogs literally constantly.  See http://www.oslobodjenje.ba/daily-news/sarajevo-canton-east-sarajevo-citizens-against-killing-dogs.  The question is not about a guarantee against seeing stray dogs.  Still I think it's too broad, in part because such policies are generally municipal, not national.

Comment: have narrowed down question to the extent possible. Now I don't think there are places where in a city you don't find any strays at all but 10 miles away they are everywhere. It may be possible in a country like Indonesia where some islands are developed while others aren't. Also I don't think municipal laws on strays change just like that from one county to the next. That's just too arbitrary. So let's not sound ridiculous.

Comment: I've not had much truck with strays, but it's not uncommon in some places to run into untethered dogs that will aggressively defend what they see as their territory- and the dog's perception of their territory may well include the public area you have to traverse to get down the road. Last time I took a walk in the Chinese countryside I was harassed to the point of preparing a defense for the return trip (and I'm comfortable with dogs in general). Strays would probably not have the same aggressive territorial behavior.